# Why does Tikz ignore my variable increment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am at wits end with a simple problem (I am just learning Tikz).  I am trying to use tikzmath to increment a variable.  However, the output of my code is 1 every time the loop executes.  Here is the minimal example (I am using TexLive 2015 with Tikz 3.0.0):

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{math,calc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzmath{
       int \y;
       \y = 0;
     }
    \foreach \k in {1,2,...,88}{
    \tikzmath{
    \y=\y+1;
     }
    print {$y=\y$};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Use a `for \x in ...` loop within a `tikzmath` command rather

Comment: Welcome! See the example of page 648 of the manual for an example of using a loop within the environment provided by `\tikzmath{}`. Or maybe you want the `evaluate...` as shown on 649?

Comment: TikZ foreach loops are scoped and after each spin of the loop the stack returns to the original state. You need to either make things global or use `foreach` mechanisms which survive the scoping such as `\foreach\x [count=\y,evaluate=<math expression>]{<loop instructions>}`.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the `\foreach` loop can't be used with tikzmath, (at least I've not found a way so far. But `for` loops can be used, inside of a `tikzmath` command.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    int \y;
    int \x;
    \y = 0;
    for \x in {1,2,...,88}{%
      \y=\y+1;
      print {$y=\y$};
    };
  };
\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is just because this is a MWE, but you don't really seem to be using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) so I would suggest that instead you use the [pgffor package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), which is a subset of pgf/tikz.

Secondly, there is a more "tikz-ish" way of doing this because `\foreach` takes an optional `count` argument that does exactly what you want.

With these two changes, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}\noindent
    \foreach \k [count=\y] in {10,...,29}{%
         $y=\y (k=\k)$
    }
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]